# How can I make renders more similar? (Xna, blend4web)

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, blend4web

1. I’m testing with Xna’s models, but there are differences between blender(blend4web) and Xna. How can I render same or almost same figure?
   Difference shaders make this gap? I want to know how can I apply every setting like Xna in blender(blend4web)!
2. The left side of following image is my rendering result with blend4web using node editor.
   How can I change models or setting to make more realistic? Comment please… (I want to make this model as realistic as possible.. But now, I think realistic ranking is like this.. Real>Xna>blend4web , So I uploaded  comparison images…)

I’m a student and study 3D modeling for individual hobby.
Self-studying with books and internets, I have problems in rendering parts. Various renderers make me confused.
I really want to render on web browser, so I’m testing with blend4web. 
But information about blend4web is really rare.
[Anyway! Followings are my real questions!]

Any comment can be helpful to me!  Please help me!..
Thank you in advance.

ps. Last image is the node materials that I used!
[image]
[image]